# How do you set Mac Safari's favorite icon

Tags: html, safari, mac

Some Site, when added to favorite, will show an icon here like github.com:

[image]

How do you set the icon here?

I've tried this code and it doesn't work:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="../apple_touch_icon_57_57.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="../apple_touch_icon_114_114.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="../apple_touch_icon_72_72.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="../apple_touch_icon_144_144.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="../apple_touch_icon_60_60.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="../apple_touch_icon_120_120.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="../apple_touch_icon_152_152.png" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="../favicon_16_16.png" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="../favicon_32_32.png" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="../favicon_96_96.png" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="160x160" href="../favicon_160_160.png" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192" href="../favicon_192_192.png" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your url path for the actual icons are incorrect. Currently you are using `../` which means that your file is located up a level. I.e if you browsed `http://example.com/home/` and assuming you had the icons in the root then it would work... but visiting just `http://example.com` would not work since `../` does not exist because you can't go any higher than the root.

The fix would be to copy all files into the root `/` and then use `/example.jpg` or if you would like the icons in a folder then use the absolute path i.e.

`<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="http://example.com/images/image.png" />`

Let me know if this is the problem otherwise I'll remove this, since you haven't supplied us with the URL its guessing.

Comment: turned out that my path is wrong and safari has an icon cache,having worked on both problem and the icon appears.